# Mulesoft ESB - To be used between different Geographies

Tags: mulesoft, mule-esb

Is it possible to use 2 X MuleSoft ESB instances (lets say A and B) between 2 different Geos and link them to serve user APIs. The applications will be hosted and linked to each GEO instance behind the MuleSoft ESB.

Thanks

I am trying to understand if this is possible and this is a design question

Comment: Linked in which way? Which version of Mule?

Comment: are you talking about where each instance can communicate with others, share data, and provide a seamless experience to the end-users regardless of their location?